# Transfer 15TB of tiny files

Tags: linux, linux-networking, file-transfer, archive

I'm archiving data from one server to another. Initially I started a `rsync` job. It took 2 weeks for it to build the file list just for 5 TB of data and another week to transfer 1 TB of data.

Then I had to kill the job as we need some down time on the new server.

It's been agreed that we will tar it up since we probably won't need to access it again. I was thinking of breaking it into 500 GB chunks. After I `tar` it then I was going to copy it across through `ssh`. I was using `tar` and `pigz` but it is still too slow.

Is there a better way to do it? I think both servers are on Redhat. Old server is Ext4 and the new one is XFS.

File sizes range from few kb to few mb and there are 24 million jpegs in 5TB. So I'm guessing around 60-80 million for 15TB.

edit: After playing with rsync, nc, tar, mbuffer and pigz for a couple of days. The bottleneck is going to be the disk IO. As the data is striped across 500 SAS disks and around 250 million jpegs. However, now I learnt about all these nice tools that I can use in future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux to linux, 10TB transfer?](http://serverfault.com/questions/149045/linux-to-linux-10tb-transfer)

Comment: One option is creating the compressed tar files on an external drive and moving that to the new system. The extra disk will speed up creating the tar files (won't be writing to existing disks in the system, possibly while trying to read 15TB from them) and doesn't tie up the new server.

Comment: *Is there a better way to do it?* - Yeah, Windows Server 2012 R2 DFS replication [would prepare that in about 10 hours](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2013/11/15/using-dfs-replication-clone-feature-to-prepare-100tb-of-data-in-3-days-a-test-perspective.aspx). And it would sync changes, and pick up where it left off after reboots.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: so you suggest OP migrates from Redhat to Windows before archiving?

Comment: @ThomasWeller They asked "is there a better way?", and there is. I make no recommendation that they use the better way. They're free to use commands in a pipe which can't recover from interruption, won't verify the file content, can't report copy status, can't use previously copied blocks to avoid copying parts of files, has no implicit support low-priority copying, can't be paused, has no mention of copying ACLs, and needs someone to stay logged in to run it. Anyone else following along, however, might be interested - or prompted to say "x does that on Linux".

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: That sounds a bit like BTRFS send/receive.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs#Send.2Freceive.  I think that can work as a dump/restore but with incremental capability.  Some other Linux filesystems also have dump/restore tools that read the data in disk order, not logical directory order (e.g. `xfsdump`).  The problem here is that the OP is going from ext4 to XFS, so this isn't an option.  (BTW, OP, I'd suggest evaluating BTRFS for use on your server.  XFS can handle being used as an object store for zillions of small files, but BTRFS may be better at it.)

Comment: It's a little offtopic, but: @PeterCordes I'd be very careful recommending btrfs for production use, yet. Lately I had some data corruption issues related to btrfs and bcache on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler It is true that these are free commands and doesn't have any reporting status if there are corruptions. Now that you mention it, I think I'm going back to rsync. Because I know there might be corruption in our old system when the temperature threshold was breached.

Comment: @lbanz: ssh encryption, or rsync's gzip compression, might be bottlenecking you.  Discussion in comments on http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228048/79808 has some numbers for compression.

Comment: @Fox: From what I've read, if you use BTRFS, it's a good idea to use the latest kernel.  They usually fix more bugs than they introduce, and it's still new and improving, so a years-old stable-distro kernel version of BTRFS is not ideal.

Comment: @PeterCordes that is why I recommend being careful. Myself being rather fan of bleeding edge, I quite understand why some people like long term support distros, which tend to stick to an older kernel. So sure, btrfs is maturing at a pretty good pace, but it's not an universal answer. Sure not without buts.

Comment: @Fox: I haven't used BTRFS myself, since XFS is good at what I mostly do.  Any comment on whether it's good for a workload like the OP's, where it's *all* small to medium-size files?  I know the XFS devs sometimes say on the mailing list that XFS isn't designed to be an object-store, and my impression was BTRFS was designed with that workload as a potential use-case.  (And in practice may handle it better than XFS.)  Reiserfs is a bad choice for a new FS these day, but it was explicitly designed for using the filesystem as a database.

Comment: Speaking of FS-as-object-store, I did some digging when this came up recently, since I was curious.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222640/79808 has most of what I found.  Traditional-filesystem on RAID5 is a bad choice.  One object-store system I looked at did redundancy at an object level, and wanted a separate XFS filesystem on each disk.  The difference is subtle but huge.  Metadata ops improve, because each CPU can be searching a separate small free-inode map, instead of one giant one, for example.  Taking RAID5 out of the picture for small object writes is also huge.

Comment: Sounds like a great little use case for BitTorrent Sync to me. https://www.getsync.com/

Comment: If you're not going to access it again*, what if you simply removed the drive itself and stored it in an airtight container (Lock&Lock) together with a packet of desiccant and maybe a bit of bubble wrap or padding? If you needed to transfer it, use snail mail or other physical methods. It's usually faster than 17 weeks. I am assuming that the files are in a different drive than the OS.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler LOL, the OP asked for a *better* way, not Windows... nobody genuinely *wants* Windows.

Comment: I'm so glad this is tagged [tag:Linux] and not [tag:windows]. I would probably die.

Comment: You might want to stick ice packs on the drives during the transfer as well, to help prevent heat degradation.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The example (and the link) you reported clearly state that the preseed phase (read: file upload to the new server) is done by DFSR via robocopy. While robocopy **is** very useful, rsync is a better alternative from almost any point of view.

Comment: @lbanz so how much time it took ?

Comment: @RahulPatil small files is around 6mb/s and large files are at 150mb/s. I'm expecting 1-2 months to transfer 15TB of small files.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I have had very good results using `tar`, `pigz` (parallel gzip) and `nc`.

Source machine:

```
tar -cf - -C /path/of/small/files . | pigz | nc -l 9876
```

Destination machine:

To extract:

```
nc source_machine_ip 9876 | pigz -d | tar -xf - -C /put/stuff/here
```

To keep archive:

```
nc source_machine_ip 9876 > smallstuff.tar.gz
```

If you want to see the transfer rate just pipe through `pv` after `pigz -d`!

Comment: FYI, you can replace `pigz` with `gzip` or remove it altogether, but the speed will be significantly slower.

Comment: How can this be accepted if OP has already tried `tar` and `pigz`? I don't understand...

Comment: @ThomasWeller where did you get that he's tried `pigz`? From the question it looks like he's only tried `rsync` so far, and was *considering* using `tar` to split and bundle the data. Especially if he hasn't used the `-z`/`--compress` option on rsync, `pigz` could theoretically help significantly.

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes indeed I already tried tar and pigz but not nc. I was using ssh so it added a lot more overhead.

Comment: http://intermediatesql.com/linux/scrap-the-scp-how-to-copy-data-fast-using-pigz-and-nc/
Using nc/pigz seems to score the highest on benchmark too. I was piping it through ssh so it was incredibly slow.

Comment: @h0tw1r3 Just to let you know that it is insanely fast. After pressing enter, and doing ls. It has already done 1GB. With rsync or piping it over ssh usually takes 20-30 mins just for 1GB. The bit I'm worried is how to verify the data once it has completed the transfer.

Comment: To verify the data run the compression step on both sides and compare the result on one side or the other. You'd need to make sure that the files are all in the archive in the same order which might not be possible. In that case you could (assuming enough space is available repeat the transfer in reverse to a different location and compare the result using a standard file compare utility. Or if space is short, transfer to a third (spacious) location from both source and target servers, and do the compare there.

Comment: I would propose using [`mbuffer`](http://www.maier-komor.de/mbuffer.html) instead of `nc`. The advantage is the ability to define a local buffer for the transfer. Plus, you have some additional stats. It is being widely used in [zfs dataset transfers](http://everycity.co.uk/alasdair/2010/07/using-mbuffer-to-speed-up-slow-zfs-send-zfs-receive/) for years.

Comment: @h0tw1r3 looks like this doesn't help either when there are so many tiny jpegs. It's around 24 million of jpegs in the folder and pigz is just using 1 core. Whereas if the files are larger, it uses the default 8 cores and is insanely fast.

Comment: For checking you could use _tee_ to divert a copy of the tar to _sha256sum_ (or other checksum/CRC tool) on both source and destination. And then compare the resulting checksum values.

Comment: @lbanz the speed that `tar` is able to collect small files is likely a disk or filesystem IO problem. The size of files should not make a difference to `pigz` because the data it receives is a `tar` stream, not the individual files.

Comment: @lbanz that simply means that `tar` isn't producing data fast enough for `pigz` to use much CPU for compression. Reading lots of small files involves many more syscalls, many more disk seeks, and a lot more kernel overhead than reading the same number of bytes of larger files, and it looks like you're simply bottlenecking at a fundamental level.

Answer (score 21):

I'd stick to the rsync solution. Modern (3.0.0+) rsync uses incremental file list, so it does not have to build full list before transfer. So restarting it won't require you to do whole transfer again in case of trouble. Splitting the transfer per top or second level directory will optimize this even further. (I'd use `rsync -a -P` and add `--compress` if your network is slower than your drives.)

Comment: I'm using rsync 2.6.8 on the old server. As it is one of those boxes where we're not allowed to install/update anything as stated by the vendor or it voids the warranty. I might update it and see if it is any quicker.

Comment: Find (or build) a statically-linked rsync binary and just run it from your home. Hopefully that won't ruin no warranty.

Comment: How about `unison`? How does it compare to `rsync`?

Answer (score 15):

Set up a VPN (if its internet), create a virtual drive of some format on the remote server (make it ext4), mount it on the remote server, *then* mount that on the local server (using a block-level protocol like iSCSI), and use dd or another block-level tool to do the transfer. You can then copy the files off the virtual drive to the real (XFS) drive at your own convenience.

Two reasons:

1. No filesystem overhead, which is the main performance culprit
2. No seeking, you're looking at sequential read/write on both sides

Comment: Bypassing the filesystem is good. Copying block-level of a read-write mounted filesystem is a really bad idea. Unmount or mount read-only first.

Comment: Having a 15TB copy sucks, too. It means the new server needs minimum 30.

Comment: If the server is using LVM, one could do a read-only snapshot of the filesystem and copy it instead. Space overhead only for the changes in the filesystem that happen while the snapshot is read.

Answer (score 10):

If the old server is being decommissioned and the files can be offline for a few minutes then it is often fastest to just pull the drives out the old box and cable them into the new server, mount them (back online now) and copy the files to the new servers native disks.

Comment: It's about 1PB of 2TB drives so it is way too much.

Answer (score 3):

Use mbuffer and if it is on a secure network you can avoid the encryption step.

Answer (score 3):

(Many different answers can work. Here is another one.)

Generate the file list with `find -type f` (this should finish in a couple of hours), split it to small chunks, and transfer each chunk using `rsync --files-from=...`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered sneakernet? With that, I mean transfering everything onto the same drive, then physically moving that drive over.

about a month ago, Samsung unveiled a 16 TB drive (technically, it's 15.36 TB), which is also an SSD: http://www.theverge.com/2015/8/14/9153083/samsung-worlds-largest-hard-drive-16tb

I think this drive would just about do for this. You'd still have to copy all the files, but since you don't have network latency and probably can use SATA or a similarly fast technique, it should be quite a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

If there is any chance to get high success ratio when deduplication, I would use something like [borgbackup](https://github.com/borgbackup/borg) or Attic.

If not, check the netcat+tar+**pbzip2** solution, adapt the compression options according to your hardware - check what is the bottleneck (CPU? network? IO?). The pbzip2 would nicely span across all CPUs, giving better performance.

Comment: lzma (`xz`) decompresses faster than bzip2, and does well on most input.  Unfortunately, `xz`'s multithread option isn't implemented yet.

Comment: Usually the compression stage needs more horsepower than decompression, so if the CPU is the limiting factor, pbzip2 would result in better overall performance. Decompression shouldn't affect the process, if both machines are similar.

Comment: Yes, my point was it's a shame that there isn't a single-stream multi-thread lzma.  Although for this use-case, of transferring whole filesystems of data, `pigz` would prob. be the slowest compressor you'd want to use.  Or even `lz4`.  (There's a `lz4mt` multi-threaded-for-a-single-stream available.  It doesn't thread very efficiently (spawns new threads extremely often), but it does get a solid speedup)

Answer (score 2):

You are using RedHat Linux, so this wouldn't apply, but as another option:

I've had great success using ZFS to hold millions of files as inodes aren't an issue.

If that was an option for you, you could then take snapshots and use zfs to send incremental updates.  I've had a lot of success using this method to transfer as well as archive data.

ZFS is primarily a Solaris filesystem, but can be found in the illumos (open source fork of Sun's OpenSolaris).  I know there has also been some luck at using ZFS under BSD and Linux (using FUSE?)--but I have no experience on trying that.

Comment: There has been a non-FUSE native Linux port of ZFS for quite a while now: http://zfsonlinux.org/

Answer (score 1):

Start an `rsync` daemon on the target machine. 
This will speedup the transfer process a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try [juicesync](https://github.com/juicedata/juicesync)?

```
juicesync local/path user@host:port:path --threads=50
```

you can also use `--worker` and `--manager` mode to start more jobs.

Also you can try [rclone(sftp)](https://rclone.org/sftp/).

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with just tar and ssh, like this:

`tar zcf - <your files> | ssh <destination host> "cat > <your_file>.tar.gz"`

Or, if you want to keep individual files:

`tar zcf - <your files> | ssh <destination host> "tar zxf -"`

Comment: It will not deduplicate, no way to resume, compressing using only one CPU.